# Fitting multiple logistic regression models based on a string

Tags: r, machine-learning, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a dataset that looks like so

```
            Q D      G        A
1 unqualified B   male admitted
2   qualified B   male rejected
3   qualified C   male rejected
4   qualified C   male rejected
5 unqualified B female rejected
6 unqualified C female rejected
```

And a string that houses the dependencies of each feature

```
t <- "dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}"
```

I want to loop through the features of the dataframe and fit a logistic regression model based on the string.

For example A depends on G,Q, and D and the first model would predict A depending on G,Q, and D. The second model would predict D depending on G.

The models would be the following stored in a list

```
m1 <- glm(A ~ G + Q + D, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
m2 <- multinom(D ~ G, data = mydata)
```

m2 is a multinomial logistic regression because the feature D has 4 unique values.

How can I do this based on the string? I'm not sure how to extract the dependencies.

Comment: You'll probably need to write a custom function to parse the string and then one to dispatch the right model. It would be hard to automate. If you could get the string input into a more R-friendly form it would be much easier.

Comment: @Noah I altered the string to a more friendly format. Any ideas on how I can get started to make this dynamic?